# Creating a folder with the name of the user that is currently logged in

Tags: file, powershell, ftp, powershell-cmdlet

I am currently working on a program that will grab info from a lot of PC's on the domain and upload the file via FTP, I need the name of each text document to match the current user logged in. Is this possible and how would I go around doing this?

Comment: This? `$(gwmi win32_computersystem).UserName`

Comment: So, just put New-Item "C:\$($env:username).txt" -type File. Or more likely, if you then refer to the location/file later, make a variable with the path-to-be and then refer to it throughout.  

Additionally, as this isn't obvious at this point: Is the current logged in user also the account the script is being run under?

Comment: No, to create a text doc at the moment I am using: 'New-Item C:\PCinfo.txt -type file' I need it so that instead of naming every file "PCinfo.txt" It will name it the name of the current user logged in.

Comment: Happy to help. =) @arco444 's comment would also have worked, but I find that WMI calls take forever in comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeeva's `$env:username` method works just fine:

```
New-Item "C:\$env:username.txt" -type File
```

But if you need the domain that the user belongs to, use the `$env:userdomain` variable, like-so:

```
New-Item "C:\$env:userdomain-$env:username.txt" -type File
```

Comment: Heh, I knew I was typing my answer out too slowly.

Comment: Sorry dude, I think I stole your rep on this question. Upvoted your comment in any case

Comment: Not a worry! I took far too long. Thanks for the attribution.